# Can I write a vim mapping that allows me to perform an edit repeat in a chainable way on the next [count] lines?

Tags: vim

Vim's dot `.` repeat feature is one of its most powerful, and the root of its power is not in how **capable** it is but rather in how *easy* and *fast* it is.

It's actually somewhat limited. For example, something that I often wish it can do is "record" a little more. For instance I have a long line in a bash script that I want to shorten to clean up the script.

Note: the square brackets I use to demonstrate the position of the Vim cursor

```
[y]um -y install autoconf automake binutils bison flex gcc gcc-c++ gettext libtool make patch ftp pkgconfig man ncurses-devel zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel wget git mercurial ruby ruby-devel libcurl curl-devel perl-devel perl-ExtUtils-Embed subversion swig bind-utils inotify-tools lsof nmap strace expect mc unzip
```

Suppose now that Vim will indeed wrap this in such a way that I have to append 5 backslashes in order to not break the script.

I really want to be able to do this job by typing <kbd>Vgq</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

But that doesn't work because `.` doesn't remember the movement from the arrow key, I have to type this: <kbd>Vgq</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

Or, only practical if my task is somewhat complex and more voluminous, as this requires an order of magnitude more brainpower to execute... <kbd>Vgq</kbd><kbd>qq</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>4@q</kbd>

Now what I desire is perhaps binding another key, let's say `,`, to automatically advance the line while applying the last unit of change, in order to make the operation numerically chainable. Then I can quite naturally do my task this way: <kbd>Vgw</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>4,</kbd>.

This would cover 90% of the cases where I feel like recording a macro, but can't justify actually doing it because it's *still* less painful to go spam out a movement key and `.` a few times.

What would such a binding look like?

Comment: As a note, `gq` and other such `g` commands don't require visual mode. You can do `gqgq`, or the short version, leaving out the second g: `gqq`. It seems like you want maximum speed, and not having to hit shift with `V` is just a *tiny* bit faster :)

Comment: Indeed, `gqq` is a nice one to use instead. Now.... I am still scratching my head about whether it's possible to use an external program for `gq` (such as `par`) while being able to leave the cursor at the start position (like `gw` does).

Answer (score 1):

Rather easy once I started thinking about it, which I had to in the process of writing the question. It is just this:

```
nnoremap , :normal .j<CR>
```

This is truly a *painfully* simple solution.

Since i already have `,` bound to `@q` to facilitate macro recording, and since always scanning downwards when using `.` is correct for me most of the time, I want to actually bind this to `.` itself.

To do this, it is important to use `!` to avoid `E169: Command too recursive` stack overflow.

```
nnoremap . :normal! .j<CR>
```

Now, reversing the order to put `j` in front can potentially make the movement flow better for the situation that I presented, however, that will have a negative impact on the use of the new `.` for other typical tasks like manually iteratively renaming many variable names.

Thus I can do it like so: <kbd>Vgw</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>4.</kbd>

Comment: I am very sad to report that the implementation of repeat.vim plugin clobbers this bind of mine. I basically have to fork it and dig into it and write a hack.